# What is the relationship between the Brier score "refinement" and the area under the ROC curve?

Tags: r, roc, scoring-rules

In the [Wikipedia article on Brier score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score), there is a claim that the "refinement" in the two-component decomposition of Brier score is related to the area under the receiver-operator characteristic curve (itself equal to Harrell's concordence index in the case of a binary outcome).

What is that relationship? A simlation of mine makes it look like there is a slight difference between the two, and and
[this Cross Validated question/self-answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/575607/understanding-brier-loss-composition) makes it look like there can be disagreement.

From the phrasing on Wikipedia, I would expect an explicit relationship between refinement and ROCAUC the way that ROCAUC and Somers' $D_{xy}$ can be related by $D_{xy} = 2ROCAUC - 1$. Is there such a function mapping between refinement and ROCAUC, particularly a bijective function?

[image: ROC vs Refinement]

```r
library(SpecsVerification)
library(pROC)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2023)
N <- 1000
R <- 1000
p <- rbeta(N, 1/4, 1/4)
y <- rbinom(N, 1, p)

SpecsVerification::BrierDecomp(p, y)#[1, 1]
res <- function(y, p){
  return(SpecsVerification::BrierDecomp(p, y)[1, 2])
}
cal <- rel <- function(y, p){
  return(SpecsVerification::BrierDecomp(p, y)[1, 1])
}
unc <- function(y, p){
  return(SpecsVerification::BrierDecomp(p, y)[1, 3])
}
ref <- function(y, p){

  brier <- mean((y - p)^2)
  return(brier - cal(y, p))

}

# Do the loops
#
rocs <- refs <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){

  p <- rbeta(N, 1, 1)
  y <- rbinom(N, 1, p)
  
  rocs[i] <- pROC::roc(y, p)$auc
  refs[i] <- ref(y, p)
  
  if (i < 5 | i %% 75 == 0){
    print(paste(
      i/R*100, "% complete", sep = ""
    ))
  }
  
  
}
d <- data.frame(rocs, refs)
ggplot(d, aes(x = rocs, y = refs)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("ROCAUC") +
  ylab("Refinement")
```

There is a huge correlation in the expected direction in this simlation. However, the relationship is not perfectly monotonic. What gives? Is it just some rounding that causes the imperfect correlation? Is the relationship between refinement and ROCAUC considerable but not supposed to be perfect? Does the relationship only converge to a perfect correlation as the sample size tends toward infinity?