# Link between Brier score and AUROC?

Tags: calibration, scoring-rules

The wikipedia article about [Brier Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score#Shortcomings) mention a two-way decomposition:

$$ BS = CAL + REL $$ (Calibration and Reliability)

with:

$$ REL = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{K} n_k * \hat{o_k} * (1 - \hat{o_k})$$

where reliability is linked to AUROC. But it is not entirely clear how they are related. Can anyone clarify how this quantities are linked ?

Comment: The wikiepedia article links to this paper, where it seems to be discussed. https://jmlr.org/papers/volume13/hernandez-orallo12a/hernandez-orallo12a.pdf

Comment: See also here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/631440/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-brier-score-refinement-and-the-area-under